# Spring FreeMarkerConfiguration Template Loader Path overwritten by Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a Java based web app running with Spring 4. I'm using FreeMarker for my web templates. My WebConfig class uses a `FreeMarkerConfigurer` object to set up my template loader path and some other settings as so:

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws IOException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer fmc = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    fmc.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/templates");
    fmc.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    Properties settings = new Properties();
    settings.setProperty("date_format", "dd MMM yyyy");
    fmc.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
    return fmc;
}
```

This works fine: views resolve correctly, including any `<#import 'spring.ftl' as spring>`  directives which can be loaded from the jar.

Now I want to customise my application more, for example setting a custom template exception handler. I've created a FreeMarker `Configuration` object and added this to the FreeMarkerConfigurer:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(new MyTemplateExceptionHandler());
fmc.setConfiguration(cfg);
```

But this stops my views resolving - it seems to overwrite the TemplateLoaderPath from the FreeMarkerConfigurer object and I have to explicitly set the path in the Configuration instance instead for my templates to be located by the project:

```
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("C:/myProject/WEB-INF/templates"));
```

Additionally, spring.ftl is no longer loaded from the jar and I have to put a copy in my template directory for it to be loaded.

Why does adding a `Configuration` to a `FreeMarkerConfigurer` overwrite my template loader path? Is my setup incorrect or does a `Configuration` have greater priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMarkerConfigurer is just a factory that helps to build a `freemarker.template.Configuration` and exposes it with its method `getConfiguration()`.

If you want to further configurate the configuration, extract it first from your configurer, because there will be only one `Configuration` used by FreeMarker.